# Isolating company network in shared office

Tags: networking

We work in a shared office which provides an internet connection through an existing wired network. Multiple companies are all connected to this network.

I would like to create a private network for our company which uses the shared network solely for the internet connection. What's the simplest setup I can use, and what equipment is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple - stick a RJ45 router (e.g. non modem/RJ-11) at the edge of your network, and put all your computers through the ports on that (or switches connected to that router).

This will basically emulate any other place such as a home where a company provides you with an internet connection and anything your side is isolated from their side.

I have just been having fun doing exactly the same thing for a client of mine who is in a business park where they have many ports and it is all managed through patch cables and stuff... It was a complete nightmare, but, this is by far the best way to go.

Comment: Excellent, that sounds nice and simple. What router configuration would I need to do to ensure that only internet traffic can pass between the two networks? Port restrictions? Can a switch perform this function instead or does it need to be a router? Thanks again

Comment: I would highly recommend pretty much any off the shelf RJ45 router. You won't need any special set up and by default (usually) all LAN > Internet will work without configuration, but all Internet > Lan will require port forwarding set up, so, you will be pretty safe.

Comment: You'll need to get a router, a switch would just extend the existing network. Most off the shelf routers have built in firewalls which would probably be worth enabling.

Comment: @William Hilsum: quick update - I bought a router, stuck it between our switch and the other network and it works beautifully! Thanks again.

Comment: @jjwchoy - happy to hear that! :)